# Find owner of shared Office 365 shared mailbox with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, office365

Is it possible to find the owner of a shared mailbox hosted in Office 365 with PowerShell as a non-admin user? I am able to find this information manually through Outlook, but that is not a feasible approach for a large number of shared mailboxes. So I thought that it must be some way to get this information through PowerShell.

It seems that Microsoft offers a lot of PowerShell cmdlets that you can run on the Exchange server itself, but I don't have admin access to it, and I don't want it either. So is this possible to solve as a normal user?

Comment: Are you talking about Folder owner permissions ? A shared Mailbox doesn't have an owner (unless you talking about the Managed-By property ?)

Comment: @GlenScales Ok, it might be the Managed-By property. But in Outlook it says Owner by the name of the owner/mailbox manager.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @OliverNilsen Unfortunately not.